# Postman: Sending Request with headers

Tags: http-headers, postman

I am trying to consume an API and the instructions are below:

```
To send authenticated requests, provide the client_id and client_secret values as a base64 encoded HTTP Authorization header.

curl --user {YOUR_CLIENT_ID}:{YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET} https://www.somewebsite.com/api-2.0/something
```

I am sending the request like this:

[image: Postman builder screenshot[1]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Basic Auth` in the `Authorization` tab. If you add those details as the Username / Password it will create the Base64 encoded header for you and add this to the request.

[image: Postman]

The `header` will look like this:

[image: Postman_02]